# Mathematica non-linear model fitting optimization - multiple calls to a numerically integrated function that does not change

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a main function that I am using to fit measured heat capacities to a certain model:

```
    HeatCapacity[a_, t_] := 
      If[t > 1, 
       t, (6*a^3/(\[Pi]^2*t)) NIntegrate[
         FermiDirac[a, \[Epsilon], 
           t]*(1 - FermiDirac[a, \[Epsilon], 
             t])*(Energy[\[Epsilon], t]^(2)/t - 
            0.5*d\[CapitalDelta]2[t]), {\[Epsilon], 0, \[Infinity]}, 
         AccuracyGoal -> 5]];
```

Implicit to this function are repeated calls to another numerically integrated function:

```
    Delta[t_] := 
     Block[{a = 
        Subscript[k, B]
          Subscript[\[CapitalTheta], D]/Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], 0], 
       b = Subscript[\[Alpha], BCS]/2/t}, 
      Return[FindRoot[
          NIntegrate[(1/Sqrt[\[Epsilon]^2 + x^2]) Tanh[
              b*Sqrt[\[Epsilon]^2 + x^2]], {\[Epsilon], 0, a}, 
            AccuracyGoal -> 5] - Log[2 a], {x, 0.01, 0.1}] [[1, 2]]*1 ]]
```

Now, once Delta[t] has been calculated once, it doesn't change, and should in principle not need to be recalculated every time it's called - which is what my current method is doing.

My question is, how can I best optimise my code such that Delta[t] is only calculated once?  Would some form of lookup table be required?  If so, does this change my requirements for performing the non-linear fit routine (i.e. some kind of discrete non linear model fit?).

For completeness, I shall include my full code with all functions used.  I realise the mathematica subscripts etc don't appear nicely on here so I can reformat if people prefer.

Cheers

```
Energy[\[Epsilon]_, t_] := 
  Sqrt[\[Epsilon]^2 + 
    Delta[t]^2]; (* energy spectrum, \[Epsilon] measured wrt Fermi \
level *)

g[\[Epsilon]_, t_] := 
  Subscript[\[Alpha], BCS] Energy[\[Epsilon], t]/(2 t);

dtop[t_] := 
  NIntegrate[Sech[g[\[Epsilon], t]]^2, {\[Epsilon], 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 5];

dbottom[t_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   t*Sech[g[\[Epsilon], t]]^2/(2 Energy[\[Epsilon], t]^2) - 
    t^2 Tanh[
       g[\[Epsilon], t]]/(Subscript[\[Alpha], BCS]
         Energy[\[Epsilon], t]^3), {\[Epsilon], 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 5];

d\[CapitalDelta]2[t_] := dtop[t]/dbottom[t];

FermiDirac[\[Alpha]_, \[Epsilon]_, 
   t_] := (E^(\[Alpha] Energy[\[Epsilon], t]/t) + 1)^(-1);

HeatCapacity[a_, t_] := 
  If[t > 1, 
   t, (6*a^3/(\[Pi]^2*t)) NIntegrate[
     FermiDirac[a, \[Epsilon], 
       t]*(1 - FermiDirac[a, \[Epsilon], 
         t])*(Energy[\[Epsilon], t]^(2)/t - 
        0.5*d\[CapitalDelta]2[t]), {\[Epsilon], 0, \[Infinity]}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 5]];

ScaledHC[\[Gamma]_, Tc_, a_, t_] := \[Gamma] Tc HeatCapacity[a, t/Tc];

result = NonlinearModelFit[datain, 
  ScaledHC[gamma, 4.7, alpha, 
   t], {{gamma, Subscript[\[Gamma], fit]}, {alpha, Subscript[\[Alpha],
     fit]}}, t, 
  Weights -> (1./err^2.), {StepMonitor :> 
    Print["Gamma = ", Evaluate[gamma], 
     " \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(C\)]\) = ", Evaluate[b], 
     " alpha = ", Evaluate[alpha]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might read a little about the difference between = and :=, sometimes called Set[] and SetDelayed[], not to be confused with == and there is even an === and they are all different. = evaluates the right hand side the moment the cell is evaluated with the current values that all variables have and saves that result under the name Delta. It shouldn't evaluate the body of Delta again when the left hand side is used or used repeatedly in the future, just as long as you don't manually evaluate that cell again. := simply stores away the form of the right hand side and will evaluate that each time in the future when the left hand side is used and with the value variables have at that future time. If your variables won't change then perhaps = will be enough for you.

If you can arrange to have all the variables except t initialized before you then evaluate

```
Delta[t_]=Block[...]
```

Then that should evaluate only once. You could verify this by including a diagnostic Print[] inside your Delta function.

You might also investigate whether you really need the Return[] in that. Return[] has been a source of perplexing problems in the past and if I understand your code correctly that can be eliminated. The *1 might also be discarded because I can't see what that is doing for you.

If you don't necessarily need to hide the values of a and b then you might even write this as

```
Delta[t_]=(a=...;b=...;FindRoot[...][[1,2]]);
```

where you replace each ... with the obvious. The ( and ) will over-ride the precedence of semicolon and allow you to have compound statements in a single function definition.

You could even do further modifications to the code, but perhaps this is enough for now.

I have not, and don't have enough information to do so, carefully tested all your code after making such modifications, so test this carefully.

Comment: Thanks Bill - I have implemented the changes you suggested and already seen a vast improvement in computation speeds.  I will look to see if there are other areas where my functions are poorly defined with := rather than =.  Also massive thanks for explaining things clearly to me!